# How to remove space in cluster in python diagrams

Tags: python, graphviz, diagram

I am generating cluster with the below code

```py
from diagrams import Diagram, Cluster, Node

with Diagram('./output/output', show=False, outformat='svg') as d:
        with Cluster('cluster'):
            n1 = Node('A', height = '0.5', width = '5', labelloc = "c", fillcolor = 'purple', fontcolor = 'white', style = 'filled')
            n2 = Node('B', height = '0.5', width = '5', labelloc = "c", fillcolor = 'purple', fontcolor = 'white', style = 'filled')
            n3 = Node('C', height='0.5', width='5', labelloc="c", fillcolor='purple', fontcolor='white', style='filled')
            n4 = Node('D', height='0.5', width='5', labelloc="c", fillcolor='purple', fontcolor='white', style='filled')
```

The generated diagram
[image]

As you can see there is lot of space between Node(A), Node(B), Node(C) etc. Does anyone know how to remove this?

Answer (score 1):

**dot** uses

- **ranksep** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/ranksep/) to adjust the spacing from one rank to the next, at a (Root) graph level, in *inches*.  Like so:  `graph [ranksep=.15]`
- **nodesep** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/nodesep/) to adjust the spacing between nodes on the *same* rank, at a (Root) graph level, in *inches*.  Like so `graph[nodesep=.1]`